# Order clause with 'like' clause in Zend DB

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysql-error-1054

Query:

`select * from table_name ORDER BY name like 'C%' DESC;`

This query work fine in MySql, but i am unable build the query using Zend DB. 
I am getting error while executing.

PHP DB code:

`$result = $this->getDefaultAdapter()
                           ->select()
                           ->from($this->_name,array('*'))
                           ->order("name like 'C%' DESC")
                           ->query()
                           ->fetchAll();`

Error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name like 'C%'' in 'order clause'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zend_Db_Select tries to delimit strings as column names, but it skips doing that if you pass an object of type Zend_Db_Expr instead of a string:

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("name like 'C%' DESC"))->
```

There's also an undocumented shortcut: the column-delimiting function assumes that any string containing parentheses is very likely to be an expression instead of just a column name.  So the following would work too:

```
->order( "(name like 'C%' DESC)" )->
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with zend but Try to rewrite your sql query in Zend like this

```
select *, (`name` like 'C%') as theFiled from  table_name by theFiled desc;
```

Though i'm not so sure I guess that the Zend Code must be something like this,

```
 $result = $this->getDefaultAdapter() ->select() 
->from($this->_name,array('*', "theFiled" => "name like 'C%'") ->order("theFiled DESC") 
->query() ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: That would work too, but you will also have to make the LIKE expression a Zend_Db_Expr, or else put it in parentheses.